Ditto in maths for repeated parts of expressions?
When solving expressions by hand, there are often parts of the expression that are both clearly distinct from the rest of the expression and stay the same for long portions of the expression.
Is there an accepted shorthand to bring it across to the next part of the solution (like a literary ditto)?
For example:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cos x -1 + 2x^2}{2x^2}} &= \lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-\sin x + 4x}{4x}} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-\cos x + 4}{4}} = \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}
In this example, $\lim_{x \to 0}$ could be replaced by a shorthand because in an exam it would cumulatively take a long time for me to write out (I write slowly) and it would distract me from the flow of the solution.
Up until now the way I would get around it is by leaving a gap where it would be and faintly writing an ellipsis. Then when I am done, if I remember I can put the missing parts in and if I forget, the marker may be understanding about seeing what I was trying to do.
What would be great is if there were an established way of doing it so that I could fire-and-forget (so to speak).

There is no established way, you can omit the $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}$ everywhere and say a remark in the beginning: "all expressions from here have an (implicit) $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}$ next to them".

I would perhaps write ''In the limit as $x\rightarrow0$" before the equations.

Writing this way an $=$ sign between expressions which are nonequal would be very unconventional. Anyway, even your attempt of writing things correctly, though usual, is not rigorous. One shouldn't write $\lim\dots=\lim\dots$ before having proved the existence of the limit on the right handside.

@AnneBauval in cases like this, I use arrows. Works well enough.

@paulina Writing $f(x)\to g(x)$ (if that's what you mean) is even worse.

Being efficient with working out is one way to save on lines of working, but one must be sure not to accidentally use a symbol that has a well defined but different meaning. Arrows (as mentioned above) are something to be VERY careful with.

@AnneBauval: a typical limit evaluation involves such steps joined by $=$ and the key is that if we reach a well defined value then that justifies the overall existence of limit of all intermediate expressions (this should be discussed and proved if necessary). This is however not guaranteed of L'Hospital's Rule so it is best to preface its use with some remarks.

@ParamanandSingh I am perfectly aware of all that but most students are not, so I don't think it is a good idea to encourage them to write things like that without being conscious of what is tacitely implied.

It is up to the person correcting your exam solutions to decide what is an acceptable abbreviation. In any other text your example is not convincing enough to drop the lims. Writing them here is more than affordable. Any other notation method is just confusing.

I would not use this shortcut for the same reason as $2\cdot 3=6+ 1=7$ is a bogus way to formulate the two steps $2\cdot 3$ and $6+1$. If you are really that lazy (which I would consider to be exaggerating) , then transform the expression within the limit first and then apply the limit. At least no teacher can consider this to be sloppy.

Mathematical notation is already an accepted shorthand. (Find some of Euclid's or Newton's writings and read them, for example—it's way longer than the way we'd write it today!) There are a lot of upsides about the dense and precise notation of mathematics; but one downside is that it's extremely sensitive to small changes (or errors), unlike regular prose wihch s incderilby rbosut aignist eevn mltple erorrs.
I strongly recommend not trying to further shorten mathematical notation; it will just lead to confusion (both in the reader and in the learner writing it). All instructors who give timed handwritten exams understand that your writing isn't going to be perfect (and your ellipsis method seems to be a good way to balance speed and completeness), but you still have to communicate your thoughts effectively.

Most calculations with limits are actually equalities and one can leave out "lim" altogether.
Typically, only at the last stage you would have to put in a limit to get the final answer.
This is probably true in most limit calculations, except perhaps for examples where you have to apply l'Hopital's rule several times as in your case, where you can't leave them out.
Doing part of the calculation without limits may actually help you understand such procedures better, in addition to saving time and space and ink :-)
Another possibility would be to introduce succinct notation for a pair of expressions that have the same limit, such as writing $f(x)\approx g(x)$ if and only if their limits as $x\to0$ are equal.  Then you could write your calculation simply as
$${\frac{\cos x -1 + 2x^2}{2x^2}} \approx
{\frac{-\sin x + 4x}{4x}} \approx
{\frac{-\cos x + 4}{4}}\approx \frac{3}{4}$$
and conclude that the limit is 3/4.

On a test or paper, one wants to show that one understands the distinction between a limit (numerical value) and an algebraic expression, as well as communicate that distinction to the grader or reader.
I suppose you could consider writing once, before the calculation starts, something like this: Let $L$ signify $\lim_{x\to 0}$. And then:
$L\left( \frac{\cos x -1+2x^2}{2x^2}\right)=
L\left(\frac{-\sin x+4x}{4x}\right)=...$
(This all assumes that in the given context $L$ doesn't have some other meaning (such as "here I am using L'Hopital's rule")).
However, I would suggest checking with the instructor before going this route.
As others have mentioned, it's probably best just to stick with the conventional way of writing limits at each step until the limit is actually evaluated.

In order to avoid repetitions but also improve rigour, I would rewrite your example as follows (avoiding to write $\lim\dots=\lim\dots$, or any personal abbreviation thereof, before having proved the existence of the limit on the right hand-side, and remembering how L'Hospital's rule which you are using twice is derived from Cauchy's mean value theorem):
$$\frac{\cos x -1 + 2x^2}{2x^2}=\frac{-\sin c_x + 4c_x}{4c_x}=\frac{-\cos d_x+ 4}4\to\frac34$$ as $|d_x|<|c_x|<|x|\to0$.
Under simpler circumstances which allow it, you may use the symbols $\sim$ of asymptotic equivalence and/or the symbol $=$ of equality. For instance (again as $x\to0$):
$$\frac{\ln(\cos^2(3x))}{\tan^2(2x)}=\frac{\ln(1-\sin^2(3x))}{\tan^2(2x)}\sim\frac{-\sin^2(3x)}{\tan^2(2x)}\sim\frac{-(3x)^2}{(2x)^2}=-\frac94.$$
In addition to sparing ink as you wanted, the advantage (over the generally admitted misuse of $\lim\dots=\lim\dots$) of such a sequence of $\sim$ and $=$ is that it never anticipates without proof the claim of existence of any limit.
